# Airflow task exited when calling django.setup(). No exception messages was printed

Tags: django, airflow

Trying to run django task with airflow.
Has a local airflow setup. Tried example DAG and worked. Tried "Hello world" PythonOperator and worked. But when calling django.setup(), it exited with no exception message.

Task log:

```
*** Found local files:
***   * /Users/st/airflow/logs/dag_id=exchange_rate_dag/run_id=manual__2023-06-27T20:16:11.857094+00:00/task_id=update_exchange_rate/attempt=1.log
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: exchange_rate_dag.update_exchange_rate manual__2023-06-27T20:16:11.857094+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: exchange_rate_dag.update_exchange_rate manual__2023-06-27T20:16:11.857094+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1308} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): update_exchange_rate> on 2023-06-27 20:16:11.857094+00:00
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 6674 to run task
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'exchange_rate_dag', 'update_exchange_rate', 'manual__2023-06-27T20:16:11.857094+00:00', '--job-id', '28', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/exchange_rate_dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/var/folders/cd/r_7zr7_x6nn32q2rk71pd5cw0000gn/T/tmpfqho3yoo']
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 28: Subtask update_exchange_rate
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: exchange_rate_dag.update_exchange_rate manual__2023-06-27T20:16:11.857094+00:00 [running]> on host ss-macbook-pro
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1545} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='airflow' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='exchange_rate_dag' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='update_exchange_rate' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-06-27T20:16:11.857094+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2023-06-27T20:16:11.857094+00:00'
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {exchange_rate_dag.py:27} INFO - Finish setting stuff
[2023-06-27, 20:16:13 UTC] {exchange_rate_dag.py:29} INFO - Finish set django setting modules
[2023-06-27, 20:16:15 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-06-27, 20:16:15 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2651} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

DAG file:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")

dag = DAG(
    'exchange_rate_dag',
    description='This update the exchange rate every day',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    default_args={'start_date': datetime(2023, 6, 26)},
)


def main_task(ds, **kwargs):
    import os,sys
    path_to_settings_py = "project/project"
    base_directory = os.path.dirname(path_to_settings_py)
    project_name = os.path.basename(path_to_settings_py)
    # Add Django project root to path
    sys.path.append(base_directory)
    logger.info("Finish setting stuff")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", f"{project_name}.settings")
    logger.info("Finish set django setting modules")
    try:
        import django
        django.setup()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("Error when setup django")
        logger.exception(e)
    logger.info("Finish setup django")
    logger.info("Start task")


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='update_exchange_rate',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=main_task,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Can't troubleshoot anything when it just said `{local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 1`

I tried to run non-django dependent pythonoperator task and they worked.